# Picturebox blocks MouseEnter event from firing?

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseenter

as a part of my WinForms application, I want to move a picturebox (blue box) onto the grid as seen below.

[image]

I'm moving the picturebox according to the mouse positions (while the left mouse button is pressed down).

Now my problem is, that when dragging the picturebox over the grid, the MouseEnter event is supposed to be called (each box in the grid is a picturebox in itself, with the event attached to it). The event gets called when simply moving with the mouse over it, but as soon as I'm dragging the blue box over it, it doesn't.

So my question is, is it possible that the picturebox on top (blue box) blocks the MouseEnter event of the picturebox on the bottom from firing? And if so, is there a way to work around it? I've thought about using Drag&Drop, but this seemed as the easier solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: While you drag a control your mouse is always on it so no other control's mouseenter will fire.

Comment: The question states a fact, mouse events are fired on the control that contains the mouse cursor.  It is technically possible to make a control transparent to the mouse but that requires a hack.  A basic workaround is to compare the Location of the moved control against the grid cell locations.